# How to let an rectangular Sprite look like a circle in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry, 2d, sprite

I tried to find a result on the internet but I didn't find a proper answere.

[Image of the Sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ1HF.png)

So i got this sprite (I load the images into it). But I need to get this in a shape like a cirlce (e.g. I want only the image inside of the green lines).
I'm just downloading e.g. my profile picture but I can't get it in a circular shape.
How can i convert it to an circular shape?

It would be really nice if you can explain it to me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html

This is a link to Unity Documentation.